How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{irx}\frac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2} dx$
Note: This is for an assignment. I am not asking for solutions, just for ideas of where to look because everything I've tried has been a dead end.
I have to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{irx}\frac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2} dx$$
and, specifically, I have to show that, for $|r|\leq 1$, it becomes $1-|r|$.
I've tried integration by parts a few different ways, but whatever I try it just becomes a gigantic mess. I even tried rewriting the exponential and the cosine as Taylor series, and while I could get a few terms to cancel I was nowhere near the required solution.
Thanks for any help you can give.

It's a Fourier transform, for the assignment you should probably know how the factor $1/x^2$ can simply be left out and applied again later to the transformed function.

For $|r|<1$\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{irx}\frac{1-\cos x}{\pi x^2} dx\\
= &\ \frac1\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos rx(1-\cos x)}{x^2} dx\\
=& \ \frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos rx(1-\cos x)} d\left(-\frac1x\right)\\
\overset{ibp}  =& \ \frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin [(1+r)x]-r\sin (rx)}{x} dx\\
=& \ \frac1\pi\left[\pi-\text{sgn}(r) r\pi \right]
= 1-|r|
\end{align}
where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (kx)}{x} dx=\text{sgn}(k)\pi$.

Amazing! Can you explain why you get rid of the $i \sin(rx)$ in the first step?

@stephan - it is an odd function which vanishes upon integration over $(-\infty, \infty)$
